# Is every abelian subcategory of a derived category a heart of a t-structure?

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories, derived-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be some abelian category and $\mathcal{D}=D^*(\mathcal{A})$, with $*\in\{+,-,b\}$ be its derived category. If $\mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{D}$ is some full abelian subcategory, is it true that it's a heart of some $t$-structure on $\mathcal{D}$?

$t$-structures were basically invented to find abelian subcategories in triangulated categories, but I would like to know how complete of an answer does this lead to.

Comment: Surely not. If you shift everything then you get another subcategory, equivalent to the first but basically disjoint.

Comment: @ZhenLin I don't get your argument. Wouldn't a shifted abelian category be the heart of a shifted $t$-structure?

Comment: Ah, right. Forgot $t$-structures could also be shifted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have thought about this question just a little bit more.

The answer is no. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the category of finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $k$. Then the product $\mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{A}$ embedded in $\mathcal{D}$ as the subcategory of complexes concentrated in degrees 0 and 1 is not a heart of a $t$-structure since there may be nonzero elements of $\text{Hom}(X,Y[1])$ for $X,Y\in\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{D}$.